# where is Qt configuration file (qtrc) on Linux?

Tags: linux, qt

I have not found it in:

```
~/.config/Trolltech
~/.qt
~/.config/Nokia
```

where I should search for it?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your system where exactly to find it. You could try running `locate qtrc`. Note that the locations this is going to find aren't necessarily the ones where you should make changes -- on my system, I only have a system-wide `qtrc` in `/etc`. For local changes, you should add a new one in your home directory. Again the particular location within your home directory will depend on your installation (in particular whether you're using Qt3 or Qt4).

Comment: Which distro are you using? I was sure there was no reference to qtrc in qt4 source code.

Comment: I'm using Debian. I haven't looked at the source code, but regardless of whether it's in there Qt has to find its configuration somewhere.

Comment: I'm sure I don't have /etc/qtrc and it works somehow. Why Qt has to find its configuration? I think it doesn't need anything more then system environment.

Comment: It needs the configuration for fonts etc. If no configuration file is present, it'll use default values.

Comment: I don't think so. I think there is no .qtrc nowadays. There is Trolltech.conf in the ~/.config directory, and it contains section [Qt]. To check if I'm right just run qtconfig and see which files it is modifying.

Comment: Thanks @KCiebiera, in ~/.config/Trolltech.conf I found [qt] section. But this file is very huge, I dont know why.